# Is there an easy way to add Color Spaces and preserve default ones?

Tags: color-management

I'd like to install custom color spaces. I'm aware that you can just simply replace the folder in the Blender config to replace the Blender ones with your own.

I was wondering if anyone knew of an addon or a way to add new Color Spaces without messing with the config file manually? Or a way to preserve my current default color spaces and have additional ones without having to overwrite them?

Comment: I'm also interested in this. A while ago I tried to find a way to add an old ACES version to Blender, but back then the only functional way I found was to replace all color management.